# Facebook on localhost using localtunnel

Tags: javascript, facebook, localhost, localtunnel

**Ok, I am receiving the following error:**

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must
>   match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain
>   of one of the App's domains.

**I have set the following website with facebook login:**

[image]

**I have the following script:**

```
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
      FB.init({
          appId      : 'deleted_for_stack_overflow',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
          channelUrl : 'http://ab12.localtunnel.com/',      // Channel file for x-domain comms
          status     : true,                               // Check Facebook Login status
          xfbml      : true                                // Look for social plugins on the page
      });
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
     }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script>
```

Comment: How are you accessing your app?

Comment: The link you are using to use the app..